# can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) with executable bundle (Gem::GemNotFoundException)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, react-native, rubygems, cocoapods

I was trying to setup my **React native** project, everything seems fine, but when I am installing `cd ios && pod install` Its giving me the following error.

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:264:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) with executable bundle (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:283:in `activate_bin_path'
    from /usr/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

I've tried many solutions in past 2-3 days, but unfortunately nothing worked.

```
Terminal Command: ruby -v
Response: ruby 2.6.10p210 (2022-04-12 revision 67958) [universal.arm64e-darwin22]`

Terminal Command: gem update --system
Response: Latest version already installed.

Terminal Command: echo $PATH
Response: /opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Users/dinar/.rvm/bin
```

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Bundler isn't part of Ruby and needs to be installed separately.

Run `gem install bundler` to install Bundler and then check the installation with `bundle -v` which should return the number of the installed Bundler version.

Comment: Thanks you, I am actually unable to run `bundle -v`, It throws the error ``` `/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:264:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) with executable bundle (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
        from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:283:in `activate_bin_path'
        from /usr/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'```

Comment: But `gem install bundler` returned successfully?

Comment: For now, I just commented out the ruby version defined in the project, so Its picking up the system's ruby version as of now.

Comment: Try using version managers like rbenv or rvm